# Jenkins "Invoke Ansible Playbook" is masking "Extra variables"

Tags: jenkins, ansible

After updating Jenkins to the latest version,

the steps with "Invoke Ansible Playbook" is masking the "Extra variables"
asking show password.

Does anyone know how to reveal this as it was before. Where the variables were still visible and configurable

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG7dn.png)

can't seem to find how/where it gets encrypted

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with Ansible plugin 240.vc26740a_625c0 version. Try to rollback to 148.v6b_13c6de3a_47 version, it resolved this issue for me